# Pandas: Split arrays and count

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

I have a column in a DataFrame that contains an array of genres

```
Row 1 genres = [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]
Row 2 genres = [Action, Crime, Thriller]
and so on...
```

How do I get a count of all individual genres in the column?

Final table result:

```
Action 2
Adventure 1
Thriller 2
Science Fiction 1
Crime 1
```

Comment: "Final table" doesn't have to match the original length (number of rows). It just needs to count up all unique values from the original

Comment: What have you tried and why did it not work?

Answer (score 3):

Given this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['Action', 'Adventure', 'Science Fiction', 'Thriller'], ['Action', 'Crime', 'Thriller']]})
```

You can `explode` the column and use `value_counts`:

```
out = df['col'].explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Action             2
Adventure          1
Crime              1
Science Fiction    1
Thriller           2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This answer is way better than creating a dictionary for storing the value_counts and applying a function to the pandas column. Nice